# How to add "required" in WooCommerce variation select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to make woocommerce product variation field required I put the bellow script before `</head>` but is not working.

How Can I do this?

It works on [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rupomkhondaker/ozco0cg3/) but not in my site what I am doing wrong.

**My HTML:**

```
<select id="color" class="" name="attribute_color" data-attribute_name="attribute_color">
     <option value="" selected="selected">Choose an option</option>
     <option value="White" class="attached enabled">White</option>
     <option value="Black" class="attached enabled">Black</option>
    </select>
```

**My Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select').prop("required", true);
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On WordPress you need to use first **`jQuery`**, then adding **`$`** to **`function($)`**. This way you can use shorthand **`$`** afterwards.

Here is your code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('select#color').prop("required", true);
});
```

*(I have add the id `color` to `select` html tag in the jQuery selector. You can either remove it like in your code)*

Answer (score 0):

For the record, if it is not required to do in jQuery but rather on backend side, which was my case and is also most efficient. I highly recommend using the `woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html` filter like so:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_html', [ 'make_size_attr_required' ], 10, 2 );
function make_size_attr_required( $html, $args ) {
    if ( 'pa_taille' === $args['attribute'] ) {
        $html = str_replace( '<select id="pa_taille"', '<select required id="pa_taille"', $html );
    }
    return $html;
}
```

This will only add the "required" HTML attribute into the wanted select, which here is "pa_taille", the product variation name you want to happen to.